# show that $ \alpha=\sum_{i=m}^{\infty}\alpha_i \pi^i$

Tags: commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

If  $K$ is a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ degree $n$, index of ramification $e$, and residue field degree $f$, and if $\pi$ chosen so that $\text{ord}_p \pi=\frac{1}{e}$, then every $\alpha \in K$ can be written in one and only one way as 
    $$ \alpha=\sum_{i=m}^{\infty}\alpha_i \pi^i,$$ where $m=e \cdot \text{ord}_p \alpha$ and $\alpha_i$ satisfies $a_i^{p^{f}}=\alpha_i$ i.e., $\alpha_i$' s  are Teichm$\ddot{u}$ller digits.

**Answer:**

I have used this result but I have no proof available to me.

I have thought like the following:

Since $ \text{ord}_p(\pi)=\frac{1}{e}$, for any $\alpha \in K$, we have

$ \alpha=\pi^m u, ..............(1)$

where $u$ is a unit in $K$ and $m=e \cdot \text{ord}_p(x)$

Also we have $n=ef$.

Using Hensel's lemma we can  derive

$\alpha \equiv \alpha_0 \ (mod \ \pi), \\ \alpha \equiv \alpha_0+\alpha_1 \pi \ (mod \ \pi^2), \\ \alpha \equiv \alpha_0+\alpha_1 \pi+\alpha_2 \pi^2 \ (mod \ \pi^3), \\ ..... \\ \alpha=\alpha_0+ \alpha_1 \pi+\alpha_2 \pi^2+..........$, where $ |\alpha-\alpha_0|_p<1$

This shows that $ \alpha=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \alpha_i \pi^i, ............(2)$

I think from $(1)$ and $(2)$, we can prove but  I can not prove it.

I need your help.

Comment: What can't you prove ? Existence (it seems to me that you showed it) or uniqueness of the power series expansion ?

Comment: @nguyenquangdo,  Sir  actually I have to show that  $ \alpha= \sum_{i=m}^{\infty} \alpha_i \pi^i$, where $ m=e \cdot \text{ord}_p(\alpha)$  but I have shown the result starting from index $m=0$ .e.,  $\alpha=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \alpha_i \pi^i$..  How existence or uniqueness of power series property help me? Would you show little bit of work? Thank you

Comment: In Cassels-Fröhlich's book ANT, the property is stated in chap. I, prop. 1, but the proof is just labeled "standard" ! You can find a more elaborate proof (for a more general case) in Serre's "Local Fields", II, § 2,  prop. 3. In particular, it is stressed that the passage from valuation  $m \le 0$ to valuation $\ge 0$ is just "by translation".

Comment: @nguyenquangdo,  thank you very much for your valuable information .